# MYSQL - Different count with different where clause in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql query and i want to join them in a single query.
They use the same table but the count is from different where clause

```
SELECT count(ad_id) FROM ad where date(ad_added_date) = CURDATE();
SELECT count(ad_id) FROM ad where date(ad_disabled_date) = CURDATE();
```

I tried with different trick (if then, subqueries) but no one work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(date(ad_added_date) = CURDATE()),
       sum(date(ad_disabled_date) = CURDATE())
FROM ad ;
```

This assumes that `ad_id` is never `NULL` (although that condition is easy to add in.

Comment: I did not think it could be that simple. thks

Answer (score 0):

this could do it

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(ad_id) FROM ad where date(ad_added_date) = CURDATE()) ,
(SELECT count(ad_id) FROM ad where date(ad_disabled_date) = CURDATE());
```